# Background showing when adding UISearchBar to UINavogationBar

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I am using the code posted below to add Search bar to Navigation bar.

I am getting everything to show up correctly but there is a background (mostly of the UIBarButtonItem that I am not able to get rid of). - Please check the screenshot for iPad.

[image: Screenshot for iPad]

Is there a way to get rid of blue backgorund showing behind the search bar?

Thanks

Dev.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *hackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 250, 30)];
    hackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 250, 30)];
    //[searchBar sizeToFit];
    [searchBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [hackView addSubview:searchBar];
    [searchBar release];

    UIBarButtonItem *hackItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:hackView]; 
    [hackItem setWidth:250];


    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = hackItem;
    [hackView release];
    [hackItem release];



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are adding that extra `UIView`. Even though it has `clearColor` background, it is capturing that `CGRect` created for the `UIView *hackView`. Get rid of it and simply add the `UISearchBar` to the `UIBarButtonItem` and it should solve the display issue.

Also, don't forget to implement the `UISearchBarDelegate` for proper functionality.

Comment: Bravo! That was the problem. Had you replied when I posted this, it could have saved me countless hours of frustration :) ... anyways ... thanks ... this really drove me crazy!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem using following code.

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20)];
UIBarButtonItem *navRight = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:searchBar];
[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:navRight];

[searchBar release];
[navRight release];
```